# SQS message format from Step Function: Flatten Input Object

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs, state-machine, aws-step-functions, hcl

I have a Step Function who's last step is to add a message on to an SQS queue.

The state machine (HCL) definition for this step includes the following:

```
Type = "Task",
Resource = "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage",
Parameters = {
  QueueUrl: "${var.queue_url}"
  MessageBody: {
    "Input.$": "$"
  }
}
```

This works, but results in an SQS message in the form:

```
{
  Body: {
    Input: { 
      // contents
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct value for `MessageBody` in the state machine definition, to produce an SQS message without the `Input` layer, eg:

```
{
  Body: {
    // contents
  }
}
```

I have tried `"$": "$"` in place of `"Input.$": "$"` but this did not work.

Comment: Are you claiming the HCL to JSON conversion of the body is causing undesired results? This may need to be a provider issue, but more information about the resource declaration would also be helpful.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - no, I don't believe so - I think it's just that I don't understand what the value of MessageBody is supposed to be. I do not believe it is is specific to HCL / Terraform, but included that here for context

Comment: @duncanhall Would `"MessageBody.$": "$.input.message",` work instead?